# Check the state of a local Service

Tags: android, service

How do I check whether the local service inside my application is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. You just start it or bind to it as needed.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make sense to me... what if you have a toggle button for starting/stopping the service.  When your home screen loads, how do you know if the toggle button should be displaying ON or OFF?  Let's say you go into the app, toggle the service on.  Then later you come back into the app.  How does the app know that the toggle button should be set to on?

Comment: There's a simple solution. Don't use a toggle button for a service.